# Mounting devices to mountpoints stored in variables

Tags: bash, shell, mount

Im doing this script and I cant see to find a way to accordingly mount the devices stored in the "devs" variable into the mount points listed in "mntpnt".

Hope Im being clear explaining myself, heres the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$(find /dev/sd{b..z}1 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
dirnames=$(printf "win%d " $(seq $count))

for i in $dirnames
do
        sudo mkdir -p /mnt/$i
done

devs=$(find /dev/sd{b..z}1 2>/dev/null)
mntpnt=$(find /mnt/win*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach without `find`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

disks=(/dev/sd[b-z]1)
count=${#disks[*]}

printf '%s\n' "${disks[@]}"

for ((i=0;i<count;i++)); do
  printf 'mkdir -p %s && mount %s %s\n'  "/mnt/win$i" "${disks[$i]}" "/mnt/win$i"
done
```

---

Output using my `/dev/sd`

```
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdd1
mkdir -p /mnt/win0 && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/win0
mkdir -p /mnt/win1 && mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/win1
mkdir -p /mnt/win2 && mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/win2
```

---

> Im doing this script and I cant see to find a way to accordingly mount the devices stored in the "devs" variable into the mount points listed in "mntpnt".

---

Use an array to store data.

```
mapfile -t devs < <(find /dev/sd{b..z}1 2>/dev/null)
mapfile -t mntpnt < <(find /mnt/win*)

for i in "${!devs[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "${devs[$i]}" "${mntpnt[$i]}"
done
```

---

As mentioned in the comments by [@innocent Bystander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4358570/innocent-bystander) use

```
find /dev -name 'sd[b-z]1'
```

and

```
find /mnt -name 'win*'
```

Although I suggest to use:

```
find /mnt -name 'win[0-9]*'
```

---

- I prefer to use globs like in my sample code, rather that `find`.

Comment: IMHO `find` commands should be `find /dev -name sd[b-z]1` and `find /mnt -name win*`

Comment: @InnocentBystander, yep, I posted that I prefer the glob instead of find. I just copy pasted what is written at the posted question.

Comment: I understand, but this is not about find vs globbing. This is about providing an incorrect solution that others might read and use the future.

Comment: BTW your globbing version doesn't work. Specifically, this part: `disks=(/dev/sd[b-z]1)`, if you don't have any `/dev/sd*` devices

Comment: Ok, added a `nullglob` just in case. It works on this side though. I posted the output of the script which has that glob.

Comment: 0+1. Thank you for updating.

Comment: @InnocentBystander, thank you for correcting my mistakes, much oblige

Comment: This community is incredible. Several things are beyond my current level but everything was absolutely useful.  Thanks so much everyone for taking the time and explaining.